# What effect does the media type string inserted in a gstreamer pipeline have

Tags: gstreamer

I have seen this kind of pipeline-running commands in gstreamer:

e.g.,

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360 ! xvimagesink
```

And I have read in some pages that `video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360` specifies the media-type. But I am not able to understand what effect would it make - is it transforming the input to the specified framerate/format/width/height etc.. or is it just like specifying the input is in this framerate/width/ht already? And what effect it would have on the pipeline if it is just specifying the input is in this framerate etc... instead of transforming.

And is it really necessary or we can ignore it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They call this `video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=25/1, width=640, height=360` thing "capabilities" or "caps" for short.

Sometimes it is required to specify explicitly what type of data flows between elements in a gstreamer pipe. And caps is the way to do this.

Why this is required sometimes? Because some gstreamer elements can accept (or produce) 
several types of media. You can see this with `gst-inspect` command:

```
$ gst-inspect videotestsrc
...

Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw-yuv
                 format: YUY2
           color-matrix: { sdtv, hdtv }
            chroma-site: { mpeg2, jpeg }
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
      video/x-raw-yuv
                 format: UYVY
           color-matrix: { sdtv, hdtv }
            chroma-site: { mpeg2, jpeg }
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
      video/x-raw-yuv
                 format: YVYU
           color-matrix: { sdtv, hdtv }
...
```

This means that `videotestsrc` has pad `src` which can produce outputs in various formats (YUY2, UYVY, YVYU, etc), sizes, framerates, etc.

The same is for `xvimagesink`:

```
Pad Templates:
  SINK template: 'sink'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw-rgb
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
      video/x-raw-yuv
              framerate: [ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ]
                  width: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
                 height: [ 1, 2147483647 ]
```

It is able to view streams of data in various formats.

GStreamer uses the process called [caps negotiation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/chapter-negotiation.html) to decide which concrete data format to use between two elements. It tries to select "best fitting" format if no capabilities are provided by the user. That is why it is possible to drop capabilities from your pipeline and it will still work:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! xvimagesink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)320, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

I added `-v` flag to see what caps gstreamser actually decided to use.

But sometimes there are cases when gstreamser fails to negotiate data format or you have different preferences.

E.g. in the case of pipeline that reads stream from socket it is impossible guess data format for certain and you need to provide correct capabilities.

You can see that specifying caps makes difference by executing these two pipelines:

```
$ gst-launch -v videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, width=600, height=600' ! xvimagesink
$ gst-launch -v videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, width=60, height=60' ! xvimagesink
```

It is important to understand that capabilities does not *convert* data but specify which format elements will produce or consume.

Comment: In that case, should I add the caps in the following pipeline since it is writing to a socket the rtp packets? : filesrc location=/home/ubuntu/DELTA.mpg ! mpeg2dec ! x264enc ! rtph264pay
 name=pay0 pt=96

Comment: I can't say for sure but I think that you don't need to specify caps either on sending or on receiving side. Quote from the [RFC 3984](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984.txt): "One very fundamental design concept of H.264 is to generate self-contained packets".

Comment: But you need to specify correct payload size (the `pt=96` parameter).